# Find first workday of current month

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on code which establishes whether **today** is the **first workday of the month**.  If this is True a piece of code is run. My code is:

```
If Date = LastDay - Day(LastDay) + 1 then

' My code is run Here


End if
```

**The Problem:** is that it seems like it is referring to the last day of this month, May 29.

Comment: your problem is with your variable "LastDay" yet you don't show your code where the variable gets its value ?

Comment: @pony2deer there is no variable set . I was running the code as is. So that means my syntax approach is wrong.

Comment: but LastDay is not a built-in VBA variable or function. it needs to be defined somewhere in your code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a simple-minded way of getting the first workday of the month:

```
Sub fwday()
   Dim d1 As Date, day1txt As String
   d1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
   day1txt = Format(d1, "dddd")
   If day1txt = "Saturday" Then d1 = d1 + 2
   If day1txt = "Sunday" Then d1 = d1 + 1
   MsgBox d1
End Sub
```

You may need to adjust the day spelling based on your Regional settings.

Comment: @gray'sstudent Thank you so much apologies for the poor question

Comment: Shouldn't your formula be modified to adjust for holidays?

Comment: ...and what about the other days, like if day1txt = "Friday"? The code looks incomplete but I wouldn't expand it further.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the main holidays which i will be concerned of will be  Saturday and Sunday , but good idea

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the date of the first Monday of a given month and year:

```
Function fwday(Optional givenDate As Variant) As Date
    ' returns the date of the first Monday in a given month and year
    ' if called without argument the current date is used
    Dim d As Date

    If IsMissing(givenDate) Then givenDate = Date

    d = DateSerial(Year(givenDate), Month(givenDate), 1)
    d = d + ((9 - (d Mod 7)) Mod 7)
    fwday = d
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that also includes the possibility to add in Holidays:

```
Function IsFirstWorkday(DT As Date, ParamArray Holidays() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsFirstWorkday = (WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(DT - Day(DT), 1, IIf(UBound(Holidays) = -1, 0, Holidays)) = DT)
End Function
```

The Holiday list can be passed either as an array, or as a string.

For example, with just Christmas and New Years as holidays:

```
Sub foo()
    If IsFirstWorkday(Date, #1/1/2016#, #12/25/2015#) Then
        MsgBox "First Workday"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not First Workday"
    End If
End Sub
```

And if you are using more recent versions of Excel (I believe 2010 or later), there is a version of this function that allows you to specify the particular weekend days that apply in your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler solution to find the first workday of the current month, where you can specify holidays to be excluded in the 3rd argument of the WORKDAY worksheet function if required:

```
Evaluate("Workday(EOMonth(Now(),-1),1)")
```

It finds the first workday after the last day of the previous month, excluding weekends and public holidays if specified.

This works in versions of Excel later than 2007, otherwise you need the Analysis ToolPak add-in installed.